# wget not writing to my specified directory - always goes to root

Tags: directory, wget

Can someone tell me what is wrong with wget statement I am running from cron?

```
wget -N --header="If-Modified-Since: `date -r testing.zip -P /home/test/public_html/resources/ --utc --rfc-2822 2>/dev/null || date --utc --rfc-2822 --date='1 week ago'`" http://www.test.com/files/zz666/testing.zip
```

The file gets retrieved OK, but writes to the /home directory and does not write to the /home/test/public_html/resources/ . The file will already exist in the target directory, so not sure if it is an overwrite issue?  I have tried with a / on the end and without.

The date on the file that exist is always a week behind the file being downloaded.

Any help and advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the -P parameter inside the header calculation:

```
wget -N -P /home/test/public_html/resources/ --header="If-Modified-Since: `date -r /home/test/public_html/resources/testing.zip  --utc --rfc-2822 2>/dev/null || date --utc --rfc-2822 --date='1 week ago'`" http://www.test.com/files/zz666/testing.zip
```

There is no `-P` option in date command ...

Comment: Thank you Peter.  I originally did not have the -P command, but had the directory path on file name and this still wrote the file to the , but after reading about wget it looked like to specify the path you use the -P option.  Having read it again I am not convinced it is the writing path and more the download path, but any advice vey welcome.

Comment: I just read your comment again and now understand! Doh - will give this a go and thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Peter - this did work, but also got an answer from Scientiamobile that I have shared.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for using wget is to pick up the latest scientiamobile.com WURFL.zip file.  After contacting their support they confirmed their original wget documentation was wrong and they have corrected it. Having changed mine accordingly I can confirm it works perfectly now. The wget instruction is as follows:

> WURFL_DIR=/home/test/public_html/resources; wget -N -P "$WURFL_DIR" --header="If-Modified-Since: $(date -r $WURFL_DIR/wurfl.zip --utc --rfc-2822 2>/dev/null || date --utc --rfc-2822 --date='1 week ago')" http://www.scientiamobile.com/wurfl/xxxx/wurfl.zip

Hope this helps someone else.

Regards, Chris.